# about XMLHttpRequest body and API documentation

Tags: javascript, rest, api, xmlhttprequest

I have the following piece of API documentation and I don't understand how to POST the compulsory parameters in red  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucYmT.png

I created the following request body:

```
        var requestBody = JSON.stringify({
          "title":"<p>message1</p>",
          "since":1530535861,
          "till":1562071860

        });
```

And then my request is like this:

```
var requestUrlCreate='http://www.testsite.com/engine2/api/channel/47259/post/publish';
    xmlhttp2.open('POST', requestUrlCreate, true);
    xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xmlhttp2.send(requestBody);
```

But every time I get error 500: "500 (Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest]: "

I understand my request is wrong, maybe I misinterpreted the API documentation and the request  body hasn't to be sent in JSON format. What do you think, how would you do it?

Many thanks for letting me know!

Comment: It looks like the endpoint potentially only supports multipart form submissions, no json.  You should try to provide the request a FormData object, I would assume.

Comment: Does it really want JSON sent up?

Comment: What about `var f = new FormData(); f.set("title", "<p>message1</p>"); f.set("since", 1530535861); f.set("till", 1562071860); /* XHR initialization code */ xmlhttp2.send(f);`

Comment: Hi, thanks the problem is solved, the solution is to provide a FormData object, many thanks!